# How to align Compose's DropdownMenu right above the text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Text and DropdownMenu inside a Row. I want the menu to drop-up right above the text, but it spawns at some weird (yet explainable, I guess) position. What is the way to do so?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code? Are you using M2 or M3?

Comment: I am using Material 2

Comment: You have said that you have a `Text` and `DropdownMenu` inside a `Row`. You should use `Column` instead of `Row`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not sent any of your codes.
But I guess you are using Material3 and you did not add menuAnchor modifier to text field.

Marteial3 sample:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuBox
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
@Composable
fun ExposedDropdownMenuSample() {
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }
    // We want to react on tap/press on TextField to show menu
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
    ) {
        TextField(
            // The `menuAnchor` modifier must be passed to the text field for correctness.
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),// <------ADD menuAnchor
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text("Label") },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(selectionOption) },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                    },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Material2 menuAnchor is not needed as you see in this Material2 Sample:

```
import androidx.compose.material.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.material.ExposedDropdownMenuBox
import androidx.compose.material.ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
@Composable
fun ExposedDropdownMenuSample() {
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }
    // We want to react on tap/press on TextField to show menu
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }
    ) {
        TextField(
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { },
            label = { Text("Label") },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                    expanded = expanded
                )
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors()
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
            }
        ) {
            options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = selectionOption)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have specific design requirements that don't align with the standard `ExposedDropdownMenuBox`, you can create a custom dropdown-like widget using Compose's building blocks. This way, you have full control over the layout and interaction behavior.

```
@Composable
fun CustomMenu() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column {
        Text(
            text = "Selected Option: $selectedOption",
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { expanded = true }
        )

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            // Add your dropdown menu items here
            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = { Text("Option 1") },
                onClick = {
                    selectedOption = "Option 1"
                    expanded = false
                })

            DropdownMenuItem(
                text = { Text("Option 2") },
                onClick = {
                    selectedOption = "Option 2"
                    expanded = false
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this eligible for M2 ?

Comment: @SebastianLore No, I edited my answer and added the material2 sample.

Comment: But in my case it was DropdownMenu and plain Text (not a TextField). Looks ugly for plain Text (M3 version) with some strange offsets.. What if I don't want a TextField? What are the options

Comment: According to the documentation, the content of an `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` should be a `TextField` and an `ExposedDropdownMenu`.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. But what are the options if my content can't be a TextField?

Comment: You can create a custom dropdown-like widget. I added it to my answer.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I've started with. Sadly, for some reason it appears unaligned to the text (see the screenshot attached to the post), being slightly above the text - or this is intended behavior?

Comment: I have not seen your code but in my code Text and menu are in colmn container, and menu is below text in my code so it will be appear below text. I have tested it and it works this way for me.

Comment: For space between `Text` and `DropdownMenu` you may have added `padding` to `modifier` of `Text` or `DropdownMenu`.